# Is there a Visual Studio - style GUI creator for Java?

Tags: java

I just started an intro class to Java at WGU.  I have quite a bit of background with Visual Basic using Visual Studio.  My class suggested using NetBeans as the IDE for the assignments.  I was so used to designing GUI's with Visual Basic's easy drag and drop interface and am wondering if there is anything like it to use with designing Java GUI's.  Maybe NetBeans does it, but I haven't been able to see how.

If anyone could point me to a good visual like IDE for java or maybe a guide for Netbeans, I'd much appreciate it.

This is only an intro to programming course, and really I'm understanding the syntax and basics in Java but the GUI creation is way different than VB ..or so it seems now.

Comment: I would say learn how to do it without an easy drag and drop interface. It pays off later, trust me.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  Using a drag and drop tool does nothing but create a maintenance nightmare and prevent all learning and understanding.  NetBeans' old drag and drop Woodstock tools created hell on earth.

Comment: Curious why you need to build a GUI for an intro Java course...

Comment: I appreciate the advice... so is VB the same way?  Every instructional tool I had at my school made you use the drag/drop stuff.  I guess that's what put me on this bad path.. I just assumed it was 'the way'.

Comment: The course covers basics like looping, decisions, methods, arrays, etc... there is no actual test.. just two performance assessments where you have to have make 2 programs that accept data and display results in GUI form.

Comment: Try WindowBuilder with eclipse, but make sure you edit the code it generates to fit your needs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should learn how to do it without a UI builder, but yes. Netbeans includes the [Swing GUI Builder (formerly Project Matisse)](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) which allows you to *design Swing GUIs by dragging and positioning GUI components from a palette onto a canvas.*

[image: gui-builder]

Comment: +1 for learn to do it without a builder.  (Drag and drop UIs == _nothing but trouble_)

Comment: Wow.. thanks.  I agree I should learn it that way.  For now though, this course is introductory.. just hammering on basics using Java as the language.  I was so used to VB so I wondered if it was the norm to not use a builder with Java.